# Из одномерного массива в двумерный php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
'names' => [                        
    ['text' => 'Вася'],
    ['text' => 'Петя'],                         
    ['text' => 'Коля'],
    ['text' => 'Ваня'],
]
```

Надо сделать

```
'names' => [
    [                       
        ['text' => 'Вася'],
    ],
    [   
        ['text' => 'Петя'],
    ],
    [                               
        ['text' => 'Коля'],
    ],
    [   
        ['text' => 'Ваня'],
    ],
]
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите новичку, как? Пытаюсь разобрать циклом, и слить в новый двумерный массив

```
foreach ($names as $value) { 
    $new[] = array($value);
}
```

Но не выходит.

Comment: А что не выходит? Получается именно так, как ты и хочешь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не получается, по всей видимости. Я пытаюсь сформировать кнопки для телеграм бота. Беру из своей БД массив names и отдаю боту, он его принимает, но кнопки формируются в одну строку, так как массив одномерный. Для того, чтобы кнопки были в столбик, нужен двумерный массив. Но после обработки в foreach кнопки вообще перестают формироваться.

Comment: Скорее всего ты не так прочитал доки и нужен другой формат. В данном случае всё работает как надо (как указано в желаемом результате). Чтобы это проверить - не нужен никакой бот......... А вот что конкретно нужно боту - нужно читать доки внимательно

Comment: @Анатолий а не могли бы вы привести код, который можно запустить? Меня смущает ключ 'names', он часть массива $names?

Comment: если `names` это часть массива как сказали выше `foreach ($names['names'] as $value) ...` должно быть

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вам нужно смотреть содержимое элемента массива `names`, то есть `$names['names']`

Это будет выглядеть вот так:

```php
foreach ($names['names'] as $value) { 
    $new[] = array($value);
}
```

И в следующий раз, пожалуйста, предоставляйте полный код